# Within a Tab I have two domains

Tags: grails, gsp, grails-domain-class, grails-controller, grails-validation

I'm new to grails, so I'm really sorry for asking something like this.

I have 3 Classes,

`Persona` which extends to `personaFisica` and `personaJuridica`

I've created a GSP with a tab and two submit buttons, inside the following directory

```
/MyProject/persona/create_mod.gsp
```

What I'd like to know is how can I save one or the other domain depending on which tab the user completed the fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each tab should contain it's own FORM element and submit button.  So then each form would submit to a specific action on a specific controller.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Gregg, I'm trying to do that, each tab has it's own submit button, but I can't find how to bind the button to a specific controller. Could you help me with that?

Thanks for your prompt answer!

Comment: Thanks Gregg I got it now...!